# Codeigniter Jquery. How to display data into cards using loop for e-commerce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Help i want to display all of this data in cards. the code already can get the result from model to only problem is to display. my plans is when i click the burgers category it will display all the data in card-body and when i press beverages it will display all the beverages without refreshing. for some reason i need to use jquery.. IMAGE LINK: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9LLv.jpg

```
   View:
<div class="col-sm-9" style="border:solid 1px;">
   <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
 <div class="card">
   <div class="card-body"> 
    <div class="product-grid">
        <div class="product-image">
           <a href="#" class="image" style="background-color:#F3F3F3;">
            <img class="pic-1" src="https://media.comicbook.com/2020/05/dragon-ball-super-when-will- 
           should-goku-master-ultra-instinct-1219439.jpeg? 
            auto=webp&width=1200&height=628&crop=1200:628,smart" class="d-block w-100">
        </a>
          <a class="add-to-cart" href=""> + </a>
      </div>
       <div class="product-content">            
           <h3 class="title"><a href="#">Product Name</a></h3>           
           <div class="price"></div>              
          </div>
           <div class="action-buttons">
           <a class="btn-outline">ADD TO CART</a>            
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      </div>


Jquery:
          function searchcategory(category_id)
           {
       $.ajax(
         {           
         url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/getproducts/"+category_id,
         type:"POST",  
         dataType:"json", 
         success:function(data)  
         {              
        data.forEach(key => 
        {
        let row = `<div class="price" id="price" >${key.price}</div>`;           
      });         
      }      
     
      });
           }
```

Comment: so what problem you are getting?

Comment: to display sir. my plan is every user click in category for example burger. all burgers will display if beverages all beverages will be display without refreshing

Comment: where your categories view ?

Comment: please show us in a picture.

Comment: here sir..https://imgur.com/a/2DsBKqG